# Correct HTTPHeader to set when asking for Json or Xml data to be returned

Tags: rest, httprequest

If I want to code a REST Service that returns either Json or Xml depending on the requester's headers, should their request of `application/json` be added to the `Accept` Header or the `Content-Type` Header (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consumer specifies the media types which are acceptable for the response in the `Accept` header.
You can then send the data using the appropriate media type.

If they are sending *you* data  - for example in a `POST`, they must populate the `Content-Type` header with the media type of the data they are sending.

Comment: Thank for a good detailed explanation.  I've read the spec but the `Accept` description read slightly ambiguishly